Windows command line: checking existence of folder/directory using \NUL-device does not work with quotation marks (path with blank spaces)
From within a Windows' batch-file I'm trying to check if a folder exists.
I once learned, that in case that folder does contain any files or sub-folders, it's kinda best practice to check for the never existing but always defined NUL-device in a folder like so:
if exist C:\TEMP\NUL (echo It does exist.) ELSE (echo Does NOT exist!)

Result:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>if exist C:\TEMP\NUL (echo It does exist.) ELSE (echo Does NOT exist!)
It does exist.

To circumvent potential problems I usually tend to use quotation marks around filesystem-paths...
because sooner or later there will be a path containing spaces, like "C:\Program Files..."
Today I wrote something like
if exist "C:\TEMP\NUL" (echo It does exist.) ELSE (echo Does NOT exist!)

and it didn't work:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>if exist "C:\TEMP\NUL" (echo It does exist.) ELSE (echo Does NOT exist!)
Does NOT exist!

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if exist C:\TEMP\NUL (echo It does exist.) ELSE (echo Does NOT exist!)
It does exist.

How come this comfortable check using the NUL-device doesn't work when using quotes?
And what would be a better way to not stumble over paths containing spaces?
Next time I might not know in advance if a folder-path contains spaces or not or if that folder contains files or not... so how do I check its existence using quotes without stumbling over that NUL-problem?
Advice is highly appreciated.

I just do if exist C:\Temp echo yay or if exist "c:\Temp" echo yay and both work. No need to add \nul.

2>nul pushd "D:\yEsExist" && =;( popd & echo/It does exist. );= || echo/Does NOT exist!
It does exist.

2>nul pushd "D:\nOtExist" && =;( popd & echo/It does exist. );= || echo/Does NOT exist!
Does NOT exist!


This answer above is given by preference, not exactly following the use of if exist or if not exist, the difference is that in addition to testing the existence of the folder in question, it also tests access to it.


The option using if exist  or if not Exist would be:

if exist "D:\yEsExist\" =;( echo/It does exist. );= || echo/Does NOT exist!
It does exist.

if not exist "D:\nOtExist\" =;( echo/It does exist. );= || echo/Does NOT exist!
Does NOT exist!


To check whether a folder has files or not, something similar to the first suggestion can be ported to this redirection (|) with filter (Findstr) + any_character (.):
dir "D:\Empty" /b =|= findstr . 1>nul && =;( echo/Has Files );= =||= echo/No Files


Note 1.: Just by adding \ to the end of the strings in the path to be checked, the command interpreter already treats the condition as true/false for the existence of ..path\to\folder\.

Note 2.: Option in If /I for sensitive case are not necessary to check the existence of files/folders, the condition is insensitive

Note 3. For the specific purpose of creating a folder if it does not exist, you can directly use the command to create it, if it exists, no error that aborts the execution will result from this action, just a cmd message informing you of the
existence. With no impact on file execution. So, you can directly omit this warning if the folder in question exists, and if it doesn't, the folder will be created, using:
2>nul md "D:\Folder"


Additional resources:

Dir /?

Findstr /?

Conditional Execution

|| and &&

If() Else If() Else() /?

Commands Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, etc.


Pushd /? and Popd /?

How does the Windows Command Interpreter [cmd.exe] Parse Scripts



Wow!
Thanks so much!
I've never seen anything like " =; " before.
There's still so much to learn... though I know I should better focus on PowerShell.

What I was actually trying to accomplish is to find a drive-letter by scanning all drives from A/D-Z for a special folder-name in the root-directory that I do know does exist... so booting from a VENTOY-USB-Stick and from there into a WinPE-ISO-Image I end up in X:\Windows\system32. From there I'd like to CD to my "MyTools"-Folder that are located on the VENTOY-USB as well... I just needed to find the drive-letter of the data-partition on the removable USB-pen.
Thanks a lot!
(unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer)

There are many "useless" things that work and are not documented, so it is unpredictable when it will stop working and/or even which version of Windows may be of some "futile use", until then, I have fun using it... d:)

I believe this path is variable at the time of execution/loading, check this with: set | find /i "\Windows\System32", test, and write down the name (like: %Windir%) of the variable and use: Ex: %windir%\System32

Or... for %%i in (Z, Y, X, W, V, U, T, S, R, Q, P, O, N, M, L, K, J, I, H) do if exist "%%~i:\Windows\System32\" set "_path_is=%%~i:\Windwos\System32"

I agree 100% with you on: "..I should better focus on PowerShell.

I think WinPE always mounts its WinDir to "X:". It emerges from the ISO-file containing "boot.wim". But as VENTOY resides on a USB-Drive with 2 Partitions - one for booting to the menu and one default-exFAT for storing ISO-Images and any optional other files and Data - it's that data-partition on the USB-drive that I'd like to find. VENTOY allows to store several ISO-files on the data-partition that are then presented in the boot-menu and you can chose which ISO to boot from... pretty neat. So booted system gets X: and other drives (HDD, USB) are built up starting with C:.
